# JQuery - cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization;

Tags: jquery

I have a session timeout script that has been running on my site successfully for many moons now. The script is from http://www.jensbits.com/2010/04/18/coldfusion-session-timeout-with-warning-and-session-refresh/

All of a sudden, it is throwing the following error:

***Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'***

Here is my Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){              
        // jQuery UI Dialog    
        $('#dialogWarning').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                "Restart Session": function() {
                    //reset session on server
                    $.post("restart_session.cfm");

                    //reset the variables
                    requestTime = new Date();
                    warningStarted = false;
                    countdownTime = warning;

                    //clear current checkSessionTimeEvent and start a new one
                    clearInterval(checkSessionTimeEvent);
                    checkSessionTimeEvent = "";
                    checkSessionTimeEvent = setInterval("checkSessionTime(requestTime)",warning*1000);

                    $('#dialogWarning').dialog('close');

                }
            }
        });

        $('#dialogExpired').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            close: function() {
                   window.location="https://<cfoutput>#subscriber.hostName#.#subscriber.baseURL#</cfoutput>/serviceticket/index.cfm?error=2";
            },
            buttons: {
                "Login": function() {
window.location="https://<cfoutput>#subscriber.hostName#.#subscriber.baseURL#</cfoutput>/serviceticket/index.cfm?error=2";                }
            }
        });
});

//Your timing variables in number of seconds
//total length of session in seconds 5400 - 1800
var sessionLength = 60; 
//time warning shown (10 = warning box shown 10 seconds before session starts) 180
var warning = 10;  
//time redirect forced (10 = redirect forced 10 seconds after session ends)   0  
var forceRedirect = 0; 


$(document).ready(function() {
    //event to check session time left (times 1000 to convert seconds to milliseconds)
    checkSessionTimeEvent = setInterval("checkSessionTime(requestTime)",warning*1000);
});

//event to check session time variable declaration
var checkSessionTimeEvent = "";

//time session started
var requestTime = new Date();

//initial set of number of seconds to count down from for countdown ticker (10,9,8,7...you get the idea)
var countdownTime = warning;
//create event to start/stop countdownTicker
var countdownTickerEvent = ""; 

//initially set to false. if true - warning dialog open; countdown underway
var warningStarted = false;

function checkSessionTime(reqTime)
{
    //get time now
    var timeNow = new Date(); 

    //clear any countdownTickerEvents that may be running   
    clearInterval(countdownTickerEvent);

    //difference between time now and time session started variable declartion
    var timeDifference = 0;

    //session timeout length
    var timeoutLength = sessionLength*1000;

    //set time for first warning, ten seconds before session expires
    var warningTime = timeoutLength - (warning*1000);

    //force redirect to log in page length (session timeout plus 10 seconds)
    var forceRedirectLength = timeoutLength + (forceRedirect*1000);

    timeDifference = timeNow - reqTime;

     if (timeDifference > warningTime && warningStarted === false)
        {                   
            //reset number of seconds to count down from for countdown ticker
            countdownTime = warning;

            //call now for initial dialog box text (time left until session timeout)
            countdownTicker(); 

            //set as interval event to countdown seconds to session timeout
            countdownTickerEvent = setInterval("countdownTicker()", 1000);

            $('#dialogWarning').dialog('open');
            warningStarted = true;
        }
    else if (timeDifference > timeoutLength)
        {
            //close warning dialog box if open
            if ($('#dialogWarning').dialog('isOpen')) $('#dialogWarning').dialog('close');



            $('#dialogExpired').dialog('open');

        }

     if (timeDifference > forceRedirectLength)
        {    
            //clear (stop) checksession event
            clearInterval(checkSessionTimeEvent);

            //force relocation
window.location="https://<cfoutput>#subscriber.hostName#.#subscriber.baseURL#</cfoutput>/serviceticket/index.cfm?error=2";      }
}

function countdownTicker()
{
    //put countdown time left in dialog box for 10, 9, 8...
    $("span#dialogText-warning").html(countdownTime);
    //decrement countdownTime
    countdownTime--;
}

</script>
```

I am running the following JQuery versions:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to figure out why it started failing? Or do you know why it started failing (due to an upgrade/software change) and are trying to get past this error?

Comment: Why is this tagged as `ColdFusion`? Seems like it is strictly a jQuery problem.

Comment: Well I definitely don't know why it is failing. The only change made since the script was put into place was a jquery tab element was added to the page. I have just tested that the script works on a page without the jquery tabs. So to answer your question, both.

Comment: ColdFusion tag removed.

Comment: weird. i don't see anything in your code that would allow trying to modify the dialog before it is initiated. Side-topic, you should group your scripts and styles so that they will load in parallel. In other words, move both `<link>` up 1 line, above the jquery include.

Comment: On pages that I don't have the JQuery tab element, the script works as it should. Could that interfere?

Comment: Could it be a jquery bug?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. It started for me with jQuery 1.11.0. Just roll back to jQuery v1.8.2 and problem disapear